# Printing specific rows from a csv file

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file set out as shown below:

ID,   Price, Description, length, height, category

With each subsequent column filled in with relevant data. I have a reader class that reads this data in and displays it in a separate demo class (by instantiating it). This is how I read the csv file in:

```
 public CatalogueReader(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.filename = filename;
    this.catalogue = new Catalogue();

    Scanner csvFile;
    try {
        csvFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnf) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File has not been found!!!! Probably in wrong place!");
    }
    csvFile.useDelimiter("\n");
    boolean first = true;
    String productCode;
    double price;
    String description;
    double weight;
    int rating;
    String category;
    boolean ageRestriction;
    String rows;
    while (csvFile.hasNextLine()) {
        rows = csvFile.nextLine();
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(rows);
        String[] fields = rows.split(",");
        productCode = (fields[0].trim());
        price = Double.parseDouble(fields[1].trim());
        description = fields[2].trim();
        weight = Double.parseDouble(fields[3].trim());
        rating = Integer.parseInt(fields[4].trim());
        category = fields[5].trim();
        ageRestriction = Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[6].trim());
        catalogue.addAProduct(new Item(productCode, price, description, weight, rating, category, ageRestriction));
        //System.out.println("PC is " + productCode);
    }
    csvFile.close();
}
```

My question is, is there a method of printing out a specific row based on a particular ID?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand your question correctly but you could change the implementation of your addAProduct() to store key-values where key would be the 'ID' and the value would be 'Item'.

Answer (score 1):

By passing the  value in method you can check the value line by line if that line founds break the loop.

```
public void CatalogueReader(String filename,String id) throws IOException{
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line = "";
            String cvsSplitBy = ",";

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    // use comma as separator
                String[] lineArray = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                //Check the value from array
                //if(lineArray[xxx]==id){
                //Print the line
                          break;
                }



               if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check by row.contains(searchID). You can  parse only when your searchID matched.I just added  **if(!rows.contains(productCode)) continue;** for this checking

```
  while (csvFile.hasNextLine()) {
        rows = csvFile.nextLine();

        if (first) {
            first = false;
            continue;
        }

        if(!rows.contains(productCode)) continue;

        System.out.println(rows);
        String[] fields = rows.split(",");
        productCode = (fields[0].trim());
        price = Double.parseDouble(fields[1].trim());
        description = fields[2].trim();
        weight = Double.parseDouble(fields[3].trim());
        rating = Integer.parseInt(fields[4].trim());
        category = fields[5].trim();
        ageRestriction = Boolean.parseBoolean(fields[6].trim());
        catalogue.addAProduct(new Item(productCode, price, description, weight, rating, category, ageRestriction));
        //System.out.println("PC is " + productCode);
    }
```